# Algorithm to calculate factorial of a number with least complexity

Tags: factorial

what is the fastest algorithm to calculate factorial of a given number.
I prefer algorithm which has least time complexity

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14456/factorial-algorithm-more-efficient-than-naive-multiplication

Comment: Great. Show us what you've tried so far.